# Type 'Partial<CustomTreeviewItem>' is missing the following properties from type 'CustomTreeviewItem

Tags: javascript, angular, angular9, treeviewitem

I am getting this error that Partial Custom TreeviewItem is missing following properties.
The problem is that CustomTreeviewItem is Extended with Treeviewitem class which is the part of 3rd party Library.

[image]

[image]

Now the code which pushes in the array is asking for derived class properties as well.

```
public static FlattenTreeArray(result: CustomTreeviewItem[], list: CustomTreeviewItem[]): any[] {
    _.each(list, function (item) {
      result.push(_.omit(item, 'internalChildren'));
      if (item['internalChildren'] && item['internalChildren'].length) {
        OnixModuleHelper.FlattenTreeArray(result, item['internalChildren']);
      }
    });

    return result;
  }
```

[image]

I would be glad if got idea what can be done to prevent this.

Comment: Is `internalChildren` public on parent class?

Comment: internalChildren is not a class or a member but a value of key which is Item,
The problem is that it is asking CustomTreeview is extended with TreeviewItem

Comment: could you add the full typescript error message?

Comment: hawk here is the full message 
Type 'Partial<CustomTreeviewItem>' is missing the following properties from type 'CustomTreeviewItem': internalDisabled, internalChecked, internalCollapsed, internalChildren, getCorrectChecked